# Connect to app with Firebase Google Sign in just like in other Google products (like Google Drive)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

We're using the Google Sign-in of the Firebase SDK to authenticate users to our app.

At the moment, if the user is already connected to its Google account (because he went to gmail or Drive, or because it is associated with his Chrome session), he will still have to click the login button (and enter his password).

Is there a way to make it very transparent so if he is already connected to his Google account, he can access our app without clicking anything ?

This behaviour works well if we deploy an Apps Script (or App Maker) web app for example.

Thank you